# How can I remove event hub partitions from Azure blob storage through code?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Event Hubs in a C# Winforms project.

I create EventProcessorHost and EventReciever objects to carry out the work of retrieving messages from the event hub and displaying them.

Part of my message retrieval process involves creating a new consumer group on my Event Hub when my form is opened. (I just make the consumer group name a new GUID).

*All of this^ works.*

When the form is closed, the consumer group is deleted from the Event Hub, and this is validated by viewing the Event Hub through the portal.

**However**, the partition objects used by the consumer groups to do the Event Hub work **still exist** in the Storage Account.

When going through CloudBerry explorer, I see this:

[image]

Where each GUID is a consumer group.  There are hundreds here over the last few months of my development, but an Event Hub only can contain 20 active consumer groups at a time.

Inside each consumer group folder is 4 files with information pertaining to each of the 4 partitions used by that consumer group.

**Is there an API call on an Event Hub object (EventReceiver, EventProcessorHost, etc.) that can clean these up for me in an automated way?  I have looked but have not found anything and documentation on Event Hubs is currently minimal.**

I looked at EventProcessorHost.PartitionManagerOptions.SkipBlobContainerCreation = true but this did not help.

**If not, is there a setting on the storage account that needs to be set to avoid this buildup of junk?**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use nuget from Microsoft for your event hub operations?

Comment: I have used Nuget to install my event hub packages.

A coworker suggested a fix for this a few days ago.  I will try it at work tomorrow and update if it works.

Comment: Hope it can fix your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work in the end.

This is really just deleting blobs from a storage account with a slight twist.

First, when creating your IEventProcessor objects, you need to store away their lease information:

```
    Task IEventProcessor.OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
        {
        Singleton.Instance.AddLease(context.Lease);
        Singleton.Instance.ShowUIRunning();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

Where "Singleton" is just a singleton object I have created where multiple threads can dump their information.  Singleton's 'Add Lease' implementation:

```
    public void AddLease(Lease l)
        {
        if (!PartitionIdToLease.ContainsKey(l.PartitionId))
            {
            PartitionIdToLease.Add(l.PartitionId, l.Token);
            }
        else
            PartitionIdToLease[l.PartitionId] = l.Token;
        }
```

Where 'PartitionIdToLease' is a

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

Now, the delete code:

```
CloudStorageAccount acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Your Storage Account Connection String");
CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("Name of Event Hub");
CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference("Name of Folder");


foreach (IListBlobItem item in directory.ListBlobs())
            {
            if (item is CloudBlockBlob)
                {
                CloudBlockBlob cb = item as CloudBlockBlob;
                AccessCondition ac = new AccessCondition();
                string partitionNumber = cb.Name.Substring(cb.Name.IndexOf('/') + 1); //We want the name of the file only, and cb.Name gives us "Folder/Name"

                ac.LeaseId = Singleton.Instance.PartitionIdToLease[partitionNumber];

                cb.ReleaseLease(ac);
                cb.DeleteIfExists();
                }
            }
```

So now every time my application closes, it is responsible for deleting the junk it generated in the storage account.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding you or maybe you couldn't do it at the time you wrote this question, but at least today, couldn't you just use the EventProcessorHost without setting a checkpoint?

That way, no blobs will be created in the storage account and you wouldn't need to clean anything up. [Here's a small example](https://github.com/sorenhoyer/event-processor-live-data-no-checkpoints)